# Redirect Nginx Anônimo/guia normal

Tags: nginx

Pude notar que em meu ambiente, quando eu utilizo o navegador normal, ele sempre força o redirecionamento do HTTP para HTTPS
e o mesmo não ocorre no modo anônimo.

Eu gostaria que tivesse o comportamento igual de modo anônimo, onde estou errando?

Comment: Este é o [pt.so], você só precisa escrever em português aqui =)

Comment: Achei que poderia aumentar o alcance.

Comment: Altamente provável que o teu navegador tem um cache de uma versão antiga da configuração onde tinha o redirecionamento pra https forçado. O que a aba anônima faz é uma requisição nova com a configuração atual, sem cache. O que o redirecionamento forçado pra https do nginx faz, se estiver usando código 301 ou similar, é ensinar o navegador da pessoa a fazer as próximas requisições para aquele novo endereço. Então é provável que a tua configuração atual não esteja redirecionando conforme o esperado.